# Fastest way possible to allocate an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, performance, resize, realloc

I have a function which takes an array of strings (*buffer*) and needs to increase its size.
So I invoke a realloc

```
temp = (char**) realloc (buffer, newSize * (sizeof(char*)));
if (temp == NULL)
    return false;
else
    buffer = temp;
```

And thus far everything is fine. Now for every new cell I must invoke a malloc with the correct size. Notice that newSize is always even and that odd strings have a different length than even ones.

```
for (i = oldSize; i < newSize; i++){
    support = (char*) malloc (LENGTH1 * sizeof(char));
    if (support == NULL){
        marker = i;
        failedMalloc = true;
        break;
    }
    else
        buffer[i] = support;

    i++;

    support = (char*) malloc (LENGTH2 * sizeof(char));
    if (support == NULL){
        marker = i;
        failedMalloc = true;
        break;
    }
    else
        buffer[i] = support;

}
```

The fact is that since I work with huge data sooner or later I'll finish memory and the realloc or one of the mallocs will fail. The problem is that if it's one of the mallocs the one that fails there is the risk that I'll have to invoke **millions** of free to clear up some memory. This takes a lot of time. Is there any way to speedup this process or even better avoid it?

```
if (failedMalloc){
    for (i = oldRows; i < marker; i++)
        free(buffer[i]);
    temp = (char**) realloc (buffer, oldRows * (sizeof(char*)));
}
```

PS: **Yes I know that pointer arithmetic is faster than array indexing.** I will implement it when I find a way to solve this problem, for the moment I prefer using array indexing because I find it less error prone. But the final version will use pointer arithmetic

Comment: Pointer arithmetic isn't faster than array indexing

Comment: @sth, I've discovered the same thing in my benchmarking - the x86 architecture has indexing built-in at the instruction level, so if you're looping over an index anyway you get it for free.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of allocating each string individually, allocate them in blocks. You could for example malloc 128*(LENGTH1+LENGTH2) and have room for 256 consecutive strings. Whenever your index crosses a block boundary, malloc another big block and use modulo arithmetic to get an offset into it for the start of the string.

P.S. sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: A variant on that notion: malloc((newSize / 2) * (LENGTH1 + LENGTH2) + (newSize & 1 ? LENGTH1 : 0));

Comment: Just need to remember not to free each string individually in that case... just each block of strings, when none of the strings in the block are needed anymore.  Also, if he's filling in the addresses of the individual strings in a loop like that, he could just as easily use pointer arithmetic rather than modulo arithmetic to get their addresses, if he prefers.

Comment: Could you give me a small sample source code? I'm not sure I understood what you're suggesting.. especially I do not understand how to access those block of strings, because what I tried crashed. Also, I don't know if it matters, but I can't use malloc(), I must realloc() because I'm increasing an  already existing array

Comment: @Alex Keep the `realloc` part... but when you're allocating the new strings, allocate enough space for 256 (but only when `i % 256 == 0`).  Then add the appropriate offsets to that `malloc`ed address when you fill in your `buffer` array.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate larger blocks of memory. The less malloc calls, the better. The fastest will be to precalculate the required size and allocate only once.

Also, using pointer arithmetic will not produce any visible difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own allocation and deallocation routines, and use them instead of `malloc/free` for the strings. If your routines `malloc` one or more big buffers and portion out little bits of it, then you can free the whole lot in one go just by calling `free` on each big buffer.

The general idea works especially well in the case where all allocations are the same size, in which case it's called a "pool allocator". In this case, for each array or strings you could have one associated pool for the `LENGTH1` allocations, and another for the `LENGTH2`.

I say, "write your own", but no doubt there are simple open-source pool allocators out there for the taking.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid waste memory is to malloc larger memory each time, when you need to malloc,

malloc fixed size(align to 2^n), e.g.

```
int m_size = 1;

// when need malloc
while (m_size < require_size) m_size * 2;
malloc(m_size);
```